# Using Optional's ifPresentOrElse method but return promise instead of void

Tags: java, functional-programming, option-type, ratpack

I'm trying to get my around a current issue I'm facing.

I have a function that returns an Optional type (an object with a few properties)

One of the properties is an url that might be present or not. I extract that url in order to make an HTTP request

```
injectedClass.method(tenant.clientKey()).flatMap(optionalProperty ->
                        optionalProperty.ifPresentOrElse(fi -> {
                                Blocking.get(() -> httpClientProvider.withHttpClient((HttpClient httpClient) ->
                                    httpClient.request(URI.create(optionalProperty.webTriggerUrl()), (RequestSpec spec) -> {
                                        LogstashMarker markers = append("webTriggerUrl", fi.webTriggerUrl()).and(append("method", "Post").and(append("behaviour", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(baseDTO))));
                                        logger.debug(markers, "Executed a Post request to something webTriggerUrl");
                                        spec.method(HttpMethod.POST);
                                        spec.getBody().type(HttpHeaderValues.APPLICATION_JSON).text(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(baseDTO), CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

                                        final MutableHeaders headers = spec.getHeaders();
                                        headers
                                                .set(HttpHeaderNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);

                                        headers.set(CorrelationId.HEADER_NAME, correlationId.id());

                                    })
                            )).then(resp -> logger.info("ok"));
                        }, () -> logger.error("something"))
```

Blocking.get brings back a Promise and I get an error in my code basically saying that the expected return type of `ifPresentOrElse` should be void and not Promise

Is there a functional and better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm a little struggling with all the parentheses and braces in your code... Is `() -> logger.error("something")` meant to be the second argument to `ifPresentOrElse`?

Comment: I know it is quite nested sorry. It is indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are ways, but you also have to decide what to do if the `Optional` is empty. Currently you want to return a `Promise` if the optional is present, and return nothing ("void") if it is empty. This doesn't work, the types for both branches need to be the same.

You can just use `optionalProperty.map()` to map your original `Optional` to a `Optional<Promise>`, and then use `ifPresentOrElse`, to do something with either the Promise or with the empty Optional, e.g. logging as you seem to be doing in your case.

But you also have a higher-level `flatMap` which I'm unclear from which type it is. Does this flatmap a `Promise`? Then you *must* return a Promise also from the other branch of the optional, and you could use `optionalProperty.map(...).orElse( <create empty Promise here> )`.

Also check out `orElseGet()` instead of `orElse()`, if you want to create the empty branch lazily (via `Supplier`).

Answer (score 2):

`ifPresentOrElse` returns `void`. What you probably want is a combination of `map` and `orElseGet`:

```
optionalProperty.map(/* code to return a Promise */)
        .orElseGet(() -> /* code to return a Promise that is immediately resolved */);
```

Inside the supplier to `orElseGet()` you can put your `logger.error` statement.